# Yii ActiveField Форма

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется форма:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'login-form',
            ]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'username', ['options'=>['class'=>'asd']])
                            ->error(false)
                            ->label(false) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')
                            ->passwordInput()
                            ->error(false)
                            ->label(false) ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

По умолчанию, при наведении указателя на поле, оно подсвечивается.
А также при отправке данных (в случае неудачи) по так же подсвечиваются.
Как убрать это? 
Просто переписать стили?

```
<div class="form-group field-loginform-password required has-error">

      <input type="password" id="loginform-password" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[password]" value="nbv">

</div>
```

Да, и вообще: если я хочу некое оформление inputов, я конечно могу прописать на них стили. Но правильно ли переписывать существующие на подсветку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=> false, 
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
]); ?>
```

enableClientValidation - отвечает за валидацию формы на клиенте при помощи JavaScript
enableAjaxValidation - отвечает за валидацию формы на сервере посредством AJAX, также не перезагружая страницу.

Comment: Код Вы выложили. Может, поясните автору, что с ним делать?

Comment: @Streletz здесь вроде все ясно, нужно отключить в самой форме валидацию, тогда форма не проверяется) Спасибо

Comment: То, что Вам всё понятно, это прекрасно. Однако, всё равно, есть ещё другие люди, которые будут читать этот вопрос.

Comment: @Streletz Добавил пояснения